# Ionic run android not working in terminal

Tags: android, ionic-framework, compilation

Im trying to run my ionic 2 project directly to my android phone. Now Im using macbook. So I try to run

```
$ adb devices
```

and the result was  : -bash: adb: command not found

If I trying to run

```
$ ionic run android
```

The command will run but nothing happend to my phone.
Any solution?

Comment: It may has many reasons. run `ionic run android --device` and  'ionic info'. then show us console outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `adb` to your **PATH** variable first. In case it is in `/Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`, you should run

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

then run

```
$ adb devices
```

and you should see your devices.